# Help with a step in Diestel's proof of Tutte's theorem in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

The proof is given on page 8 of the [pdf here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch2.pdf) which has page number 42.

We let $G=(V,E)$ be an edge-maximal graph without a 1-factor—that is, if we add any edge to $G$, the resulting graph has a 1-factor. We need to show that a set $S$ exists such that all components of $G-S$ are complete and every vertex $s\in S$ is adjacent to all the vertices of $G-S$.

Let $S$ be the set of all vertices of $G$ which are adjacent to every other vertex in $G$. Suppose that $S$ does not satisfy the above condition. Then there are two nonadjacent vertices $a,a'$ in some component of $G-S$. This implies there are vertices $a,b,c,d$ with $ab\in E$, $bc\in E$, but $ac\notin E$ and $bd\notin E$. Then there is a 1-factor $M_1$ of $G+ac$ and a 1-factor $M_2$ of $G+bd$. Now let $P=d\dots v$ be a maximal path in $G$ with its first edge in $M_1$ and all subsequent edges alternately in $M_2$ and $M_1$.

So far so good, but now we get to, "if the last edge of $P$ is in $M_1$ then $v=b$, since otherwise we could continue $P$". I just can't for the life of me see how this is true. How must it be true that $b$ is the only vertex incident with a matched edge in $M_1$ and no matched edge in $M_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_2$ is a 1-factor of $G+bd$, and $G$ does not have a 1-factor, so $bd$ must be an edge of $M_2$.
This means that the edges of $M_2$ that are in $G$ hit all vertices except $b$ and $d$.
So if we cannot continue $P$, it must end with either $b$ or $d$.

We also know that $P$ begins and ends with an edge of $M_1$.
Since $M_1$ only has independent edges, the last one cannot be incident with the first one,
in other words, the last one cannot hit $d$, since $P$ begins with $d$.

So $P$ must end with $b$.